# How do I install nvidia GT 440 graphics drivers on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 12.10

I have been having a problem where the screen 'blinks' twice every 5-10 seconds. The blink is like somebody is turning my monitor off 2 times quickly. I believe this is due to my graphics drivers, if not could anybody please explain what it is as I am a beginner to Ubuntu. I try to download the correct graphics card drivers but it comes up with a .run file and I am not sure what to do from here? I don't know how to install the drivers basically, if anybody could tell me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To install the nvidia drivers, do the following:

1. Open the program Terminal.
2. Run the command `sudo apt-get install linux-source`.
3. Run the command `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`.
4. Run the command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`.

Reboot your computer.  You should have the nvidia driver installed now.  Normally there is an easier, graphical way to do it, but there is a bug that causes problems doing it that way...

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I have updated this answer.  You may want to install the packgage linux-headers-generic, so that when we get a kernel update, your install isn't broken. Just run the command `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` from the Terminal and you should be good to go.